# Submitting a form React - MUI v5, delivers a wrong value from one field

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I have a react from made with MUI (I'm using MUI v5))

Everything works ok, until I hit submit.

The submitted values are ok except for the select, which is delayed, I mean, suppose I select the first value, and the default value is 0, then hitting submit will say that the selected value is 0, then, if I hit submit once more, immediately, then it says the correct answer, see, it’s kind of delayed by one render of the component.

I wanted to have all values in one object state, but I had to separate some of them, like a date value (uploadDate) and the select value (category value)
This is the simplified code:

```
const AddVideoAndCategories = ({
    addVideo,
    getAllCategoriesWithoutVideos,
    categories,
    categoriesLoaded,
    resetDrawerMenuItems,
    addDrawerItem,
    setCurrentDrawerMenuItems
}) => {
    const [ formValues, setFormValues ] = useState(defaultValues);
    const [ uploadDate, setUploadDate ] = React.useState(today());
    const [ selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory ] = useState('');
    const { handleSubmit, reset, control } = useForm();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!categoriesLoaded) {
            /// Load the categories from the back end to redux
        }
    }, []);

    const handleCategoryChange = (e) => {
        setSelectedCategory(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        let { name, value } = e.target;

        setFormValues({
            ...formValues,
            [name]: value
        });
    };

    async function handleCtrlClick(target) {
        /// allow pasting the clipboard with just ctrl click
    }

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        // In that case, event.ctrlKey does the trick.
        if (event.ctrlKey) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            handleCtrlClick(event.target);
        }
    };

    const myHandleSubmit = () => {
        let arr = selectedCategory.split('^'); /// This trick allowed me to show the selected category name instead of the categoryId
        setFormValues({
            ...formValues,
            uploadDate: uploadDate,
            categoryId: arr[0]
        });

        alert(JSON.stringify(formValues, null, 4));
    };

    const handleReset = () => {
        /// resets all fields
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Box
                component="form"
                sx={{
                    '& > :not(style)': { m: 1, width: '30ch', marginTop: '50px', marginBottom: '0' }
                }}
                noValidate
                autoComplete="off"
            >
                <Stack spacing={3}>
                    <TextField
                        …
                    />
                    <TextField
                        …
                    />
                    <TextField
                        …
                    />

                    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                        <DatePicker
                            id="author-uploadDate"
                            name="uploadDate"
                            label="Video UploadDate"
                            value={uploadDate}
                            defaultValues={uploadDate}
                            onChange={(newValue) => {
                                setUploadDate(newValue);
                            }}
                            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                        />
                    </LocalizationProvider>

                    <TextField
                        …
                    />

                    <FormControl sx={{ minWidth: 120, maxWidth: '500px', width: '270px' }}>
                        <InputLabel id="video categories">Video Category</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                            labelId="video categories"
                            id="simple-select"
                            value={selectedCategory}
                            label="Video Category"
                            onChange={handleCategoryChange}
                        >
                            {categories.map((category) => {
                                return (
                                    <MenuItem value={category.id.toString() + '^' + category.name}>
                                        {category.name}
                                    </MenuItem>
                                );
                            })}
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>

                    <TextField
                        …
                    />
                </Stack>
                <Button variant="contained" endIcon={<SendIcon />} size="medium" onClick={myHandleSubmit}>
                    Submit
                </Button>
                <Button variant="outlined" startIcon={<DeleteIcon />} size="medium" onClick={handleReset}>
                    Reset
                </Button>
            </Box>
        </form>
    );
};

// title, origin, author, uploadDate, url, excerpt
const defaultValues = {
    title: '',
    origin: 'Vimeo',
    author: '',
    uploadDate: today(),
    categoryId: 0,
    url: '',
    excerpt: ''
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
…
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
…
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddVideoAndCategories);
```

Can somebody see why that happens?

Comment: This is a simple setstate async/stale closure issue. You cannot update `formValues` and expect to be able to console log the new object immediately after.

Comment: Unrelated, it looks like you have two forms - one at the root level and another by specifying `form` as the component type of `Box`. You also are calling your submit function directly from they button when you should probably remove the click handler and just make the button type "submit".

Comment: Finally, your "trick" to show the selected category name is unnecessary. Just use the id as the input value (you should also specify it as the `key` since it's dynamic). It will still show the name in the select box

Comment: Thank you, Brian, I made the suggested revisions, and now it's working.